# window.location not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have a problem in JQuery and I am trying to make a page that will redirect to another page after choosing what type of loan using a radio button.  Unfortunately, `window.location` is not working.

```
  <script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
  <script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#apply_but').click(function () {
         var rad_but = $('input[@name="loan_type"]:checked');
         if($(rad_but).val() == "loan_business_corp"){
            $(location).attr('href','sss_pension_loan_step5.php');
         }
         else if($(rad_but).val() == "loan_business_sol"){
           alert("lol");
         }
       });
     });
  </script>
```

Comment: Ugh. Please only add the relevant HTML.

Comment: there's no `window.location` in your example code

Comment: Please properly format your code

Comment: @F.Calderan there is - it's `location`.

Comment: Is the "lol" alert working if you select the load_business_sol value? Do you get any browser errors/firebug feedback as to why the redirect is failing?

Comment: @Alnitak didn't think to look inside a jQuery selector :)

Answer (score 2):

`window.location` isn't a DOM object so, you **can't** write:

```
$(window.location).attr('href', ...);
```

`window.location.href` is just a *property* of `window.location` that just happens to have the same name as the `href` *attribute* of an `<a>` tag.

Instead you must write:

```
window.location.href = ...;
```

Comment: eureka!.. tnx guys for helping, i found the answer and its just a common beginner programmer mistake. I forgot to put "return false;".

Comment: @user978064 if you _intend_ to redirect to a new page there's no need to `return false` - setting `window.location.href` will instantly cause the running script to stop and cause the new page to load.

Answer (score 1):

why to use jquery for loading a page javascript can do it like:

```
window.location.href='<url>';
```

Answer (score 0):

**By Using jQuery we can Do it as follows :)**

```
<input type="radio" name="url" value="url.com"  id="url" /> op1<br />
<input type="radio" name="url" value="url1.com" id="url" /> op2<br />
<input type="radio" name="url" value="url2.com" id="url" /> op3<br />
 <script>
    ​function displayVals() {
           window.location.href=$('input:radio:checked').val();
          //alert($('input:radio:checked').val());
    }



    $('input').click(function() {
        displayVals();
    });​
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ipsjolly/rL6WK/